# How to get data from optional group in Python regexp?

Tags: python, regex, regex-group, regex-greedy

**data 1**

Hi there:
**first**

Hello:
**second**

welcome:
**third**

data 2

Hi there:
**first**

welcome:
**third**

My intention is to write a regex code to get the above bold text.
In data2 **Hello:** is missing. how to handle it in a single regex?

**My code is**:

```
import re

mat = re.search(r"Hi there:\n(.*)\n(Hello:\n(.*))?\nwelcome:\n(.*)", data1, re.DOTALL)
print(mat)
print(mat.group(1))
print(mat.group(2))
print(mat.group(3))
```

output I'm getting:

```
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x10694aca8>
first   ->
```

Hello:
second
None
None

Answer (score 0):

You could use 3 groups and make the second group optional. You can omit the `re.DOTALL` and instead match 0 or more whitespace chars `\s*` after matching the newline.

```
(Hi there:)\r?\n\s*(?:(Hello:)\r?\n\s*)?(welcome:)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1TIu3R/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/jsKc56)

In the code you could for example check if group 2 is not None

```
import re

regex = r"(Hi there:)\r?\n\s*(?:(Hello:)\r?\n\s*)?(welcome:)"

data1 = ("Hi there:\n\n"
    "Hello:\n\n"
    "welcome:")

mat = re.search(regex, data1)

if mat:
    print(mat.group(1))
    if mat.group(2) is not None:
        print(mat.group(2))
    print(mat.group(3))
```